# Grayflame feats requirement

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, class-feature

The [grayflame weapons](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/advancedPlayersGuide/magicItems/weapons.html#grayflame) description says that:

> ... When the wielder spends a swift action to channel energy **through the weapon**, it ignites...

The channel energy ability feature description doesn't say anything about channel "through a weapon". How can classes with channel energy feature (clerics, life oracles and shamans, ecc...) use this weapons? Are they forced to pick the [Channel Smite](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/feats.html#channel-smite) feat?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wielder of weapon with magic weapon special ability [*grayflame*](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/advancedPlayersGuide/magicItems/weapons.html#grayflame) should be allowed by the magic weapon special ability to take a swift action to charge the weapon by expending a use of the supernatural ability channel energy. While the weapon special ability could've been phrased to make *how* to use it more obvious, *limiting* the magic weapon special ability's use to creatures that can *already* take a swift action to channel energy into a weapon makes the magic weapon special ability nearly useless. (Even the question's example of the feat [Channel Smite](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/feats.html#channel-smite) doesn't *specifically* allow a creature to channel energy into the creature's weapon!)

Channeling energy into a weapon is a thing for a couple of different weapons—there's also the [*void scythe*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/specific-magic-weapons/void-scythe/), for example, although how to use that weapon is more obvious from its description.

Note that when the magic weapon special ability *grayflame* appeared in the *Advanced Player's Guide* (2010), *Pathfinder* was barely a year old and still drawing a lot of its inspiration from the game on which *Pathfinder* is based, *Dungeons & Dragons 3.5e*. In that game's *Player's Handbook*, players are told in Other Uses for Positive or Negative Energy that "[p]ositive or negative energy may have uses other than affecting undead [which is typically all channeling energy did in that game]. For example, a holy site might be guarded by a magic door that opens for any good cleric who can" channel enough positive energy into it (160). Likewise, an example in that game's *Player's Handbook* of the skill Use Magic Device has iconic rogue Lidda finding "a magic chalice that turns regular water into holy water when a cleric or an experienced paladin channels positive energy into it…" (86).

In a similar fashion, a player coming to *Pathfinder* from *D&D 3.5e* in 2010 would've likely *automatically* assumed the magic weapon special ability *grayflame* allowed the weapon's wielder to channel positive energy into the weapon, that being just another use of channel energy like as in that other game. However, nearly a decade on, I totally agree the description of the magic weapon special ability *grayflame* could stand a revision.

Comment: Thank you, the door and holy water example clarify my doubts.

Answer (score 1):

As I read it, [Grayflame](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/magic-weapon-special-abilities/grayflame/) inherently grants its wielder the ability to choose to channel their Channel through the weapon to activate the effect. That is, the ability could have been worded "As a swift action, the wielder may expend one use of Channel Energy to ignite ...".

This is akin to [Spell Storing](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/magic-weapon-special-abilities/spell-storing/) letting a caster cast a spell that usually couldn't target a weapon into the weapon.